# .NET Core 2.0 BasePath Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Just started a fresh .NET Core 2.0 app, but getting weird sudden behaviour, can't seem to find anything.

The following error pops up when hitting the `.Run()` of my `BuildWebHost().`:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: A path base can only be configured using IApplicationBuilder.UsePathBase().
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.<BindAddressAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.<BindAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.<BindAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.<StartAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext()
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.0\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Exception","time":"2017-09-25T13:26:29.6923656Z","tags":{"ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1"},"data":{"baseType":"ExceptionData","baseData":{"ver":2,"properties":{"{OriginalFormat}":"Unable to start Kestrel.","CategoryName":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel","Exception":"System.InvalidOperationException: A path base can only be configured using IApplicationBuilder.UsePathBase().\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.<BindAddressAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.<BindAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.<BindAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.<StartAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext()","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","DeveloperMode":"true"},"exceptions":[{"id":47609378,"typeName":"System.InvalidOperationException","message":"Unable to start Kestrel.","hasFullStack":true,"parsedStack":[{"level":0,"method":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder+<BindAddressAsync>d__7.MoveNext","assembly":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60"},{"level":1,"method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"},{"level":2,"method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"},{"level":3,"method":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder+AddressesStrategy+<BindAsync>d__2.MoveNext","assembly":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60"},{"level":4,"method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"},{"level":5,"method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"},{"level":6,"method":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder+<BindAsync>d__0.MoveNext","assembly":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60"},{"level":7,"method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"},{"level":8,"method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"},{"level":9,"method":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer+<StartAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext","assembly":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60"}]}],"severityLevel":"Critical"}}}
The thread 0x1d7c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x25c0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
A path base can only be configured using IApplicationBuilder.UsePathBase().
```

Here's my Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Here's my Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        //Swagger
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
            {
                Title = "2Commit Blogpost API",
                Version = "v1"
            });
        });

        //Mediatr
        services.AddScoped<IMediator, Mediator>();
        services.AddTransient<SingleInstanceFactory>(sp => sp.GetService);
        services.AddTransient<MultiInstanceFactory>(sp => sp.GetServices);
        services.AddMediatorHandlers(typeof(Startup).Assembly);

        //MongoDB
        services.Configure<MongoSettings>(s =>
        {
            s.Database = Configuration.GetSection("MongoConnection:Database").Value;
        });
        services.AddSingleton<IMongoClient, MongoClient>(client => new MongoClient(Configuration.GetSection("MongoConnection:ConnectionString").Value));

        //BL
        services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();

        //DAL
        services.AddTransient<IRepository, MongoRepository>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //Swagger
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "BlogPost API");
        });

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Can't seem to wrap my head around this one!

UPDATE 1 :

The error only pops up when running my project from the command line, when running it trough IIS Express, no errors.

Here are my launchSettings

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51592/swagger",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "API": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/swagger"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Though not related. You should have an equivalent configure services in your BL and shift the reference to the DAL into there. With your current set up, you have direct access to the DAL from your upper layer and this opens up the potential to negate the BL layer. Ideally, the top layer should not know anything about the DAL.

Comment: That's actually something that bugged me for a while now, but didn't take the time to consider it. You've a concrete example on how I should shift my BL <-> DAL stuff into m BL?

Comment: I do, I'll try and dig it out.....I don't have it at the site I'm in at the moment. but I'll show you how I did it on an update to this question.

Comment: Do you have an e-mail? I cant find anywhere on this site to send a private mail. I have some code sample for you as promised that shows you how to push the reference to your DAL down the stack.

Comment: I already figured it out, thanks !

Comment: Ok. So you used Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection and created extension classes in your BAL and DAL. No worries glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

OK, in 1.X you could just add a base path to your applicationUrl in your launchOptions while running from command line, now it only works when using IIS.

in my launchSettings, changing my CLI profile from using

`"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/swagger"`

to

`"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000"`

did the trick.

Comment: You could also continue to access this from http://localhost:5000/swagger by making the change above and then adding the following to the Configure section of Startup.cs:

app.UsePathBase("/swagger").UseMvc();

Answer (score 7):

As @TanguyB said, you should change applicationUrl
But then you may set

`"launchUrl": "http://localhost:5000/swagger"`

to run your application on Swagger page

Answer (score 1):

I am using **Core 3.0**: I removed `https` url and kept only `http` url

Comment: That's good, but the title is about Core 2.0, so this is a doubtful answer