# Startup.cs missing. How to change the start up URL of ASP.NET Core MVC application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I am using VS 2022 and ASP.NET Core 6 MVC.

When I debug my app, it is starting with `https://localhost:7043/`, but I want it to start with `https://localhost:7043/calculate`.

How to force my app to start from that URL? I don't see a `startup.cs` anywhere.

I am learning ASP.NET Core MVC and I don't have much code to share.

Added this my `launchsettings.json` according to one of answer here still no effect:

[image]

Comment: Startup.cs is combined with  Program.cs. Do you know how to change the url in startup?

Comment: From[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749411/system-invalidoperationexception-a-path-base-can-only-be-configured-using-iapp) you can  change the start up URL, but it need the calculate view.

Answer (score 1):

you can set `applicationUrl` in `launchSettings.json`

```
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7043/calculate",
    ....
```

You can also define urls in the program.cs file:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            webBuilder.UseUrls("https://localhost:7043/calculate");
        });
```

this link [Set start URL in ASP.NET Core](https://procodeguide.com/programming/how-to-set-start-url-in-aspnet-core/)  has useful information...

Comment: I changed according to your first method. Set the startup to IIS. Still load in same way. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

As of .NET 7 the following code at the end of your Program.cs file works so your app is listening there if that's what you're asking

```
app.Run("http://localhost:5001");
```